# how to solve : Object is possibly 'null'. in angular routing?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

As I am doing angular heroes tutorial from angular documentation. I am getting an error

> Object is possibly 'null'.

```
getHero(): void {
const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
this.heroService.getHero(id)
  .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
```

}

in **hero-detail.component.ts**

link for the whole code [hero-detail component](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#final-code-review)

I have seen so many answers that to make it false in **config.json**.
I need help with how to solve this, but not suppressing it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it in two steps

```
getHero(): void {
  const param=this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  const id = param?+param:0;
  this.heroService.getHero(id)
    .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
}
```

Comment: so should we access another variable whenever we are using routing?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the stray plus sign combined with the fact the item `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')` might actually be null according to the Typescript type system so it's not a legitimate operand for `+`.

I recreated the same error with this code at [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFAWBLMBzAXNATslAfMArgDZEDcAsAFBUBmBYwUi4MKAplABJuYgAUAShhoYANxCIAJjADeVUJFhSYAXhgBqBDgqUAvkA)

```
const thing:string|null;

function getHero() : void {
const id = +thing;
}
```

Note the line that says...

```
const id = +thing;
```

[image]

If the use of `+` was intended as per Elisio's comment below, then you need to do something to guard the command, so that getHero not run at all when id is null, or that a reliable substitute value is provided for the id before running it. So long as there's a possibility it's null then

Typescript can't guarantee the operation will complete. This is good because it forces you to do the checks and add the safety.

Comment: in this case you can `const id=thing?+thing:0`

Comment: My interpretation of the error was that the plus sign had snuck in there and wasn't intended, but was creating a compiler error the OP couldn't interpret in a statement that was meant to just be a simple assignment like... const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')

Comment: I'm not pretty sure, but I think that the error is that you can not "operate" over a variable that can be null, but you can equal a variable to another that is (or can be) null. the "+" is a short way to convert in number a string that you know is a number: `+"2"`is `2` is like say `Number("2")`

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I've not used that but now I know.